# Abstractions in call-by-push-value

Tags: lambda-calculus

In ["Call-by-push-value: A subsuming paradigm."](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-007-0954-6_2) (Levy, Paul Blain. Springer, Dordrecht, 2003. 27-47) terms of the lambda calculus get split in to values and computations, with the slogan "A value is, a computation does".

What I don't understand is: why are abstractions computations and not values? Intuitively a function does not do anything and can be used as data. It will only do something when applied to something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

thanks for your interest in call-by-push-value.  The fact that functions (all functions, not just lambda-abstractions) are computations is the main difference between call-by-push-value and call-by-value (where functions are values), and it does seem strange at first.  But the mystery is (somewhat) resolved when you see the CK-machine, which is a kind of operational semantics that uses a computation and a stack.  In terms of that machine, a function of type A -> B is a computation that aims to pop a value of type A and then behave as a computation of type B.  For example:

```
    print "hello".
    lambda x.
    print "hello again".
    return x
```

is a computation that first prints "hello", then pops x ("lambda" means "pop"), then prints "hello again", then returns x.  And actually, the same phenomenon of "lambda" as "pop" is present in call-by-name; that's why call-by-push-value manages to subsume call-by-name.

I hope that helps!  I should also say that the origin of call-by-push-value is that it was empirically observed within the models.  The slogan was designed to fit the language and not the other way round.  But that's just saying probably a less helpful answer, because it's just saying "the language is that way because the models say so".

Comment: What is the advantage of CBPV over FG-CBV? It seems to me that FG-CBV does everything that CBPV does (explicit evaluation order, thunks can be done with abstractions).